# How to see total number of reviews in each review type

Tags: support, review-queues, badges

In StackOverflow, the badges awarded for reviewing posts are custodian, Reviewer, and Steward at 1 review, 250 reviews, and 1000 reviews respectively. As far as I know, these badges are awarded according to the number of reviews done under each type of reviews:

- First Posts
- Late answers
- Triage

**Example:** 
If you have completed 250 reviews under the **First Posts** reviews category, then you will be awarded the 'Reviewer' badge. Again if you have completed 250 reviews under the **Late answers** reviews category, again you will be awarded the 'Reviewer' badge.

I would like to add the following section from the StackOverflow badge descriptions for further clarification.
[image: reviewer badges-stackoverflow]

**The problem:**

My problem is how can we know how many reviews I have done under each category.?

I do know that, We can see the total number of reviews we have done by visiting ***Reviews*** under the ***All actions*** tab as follows.
[image: total number of reviews]

Above mentioned four reviews are four different types of reviews. And I got a custodian badge for each review type. Nevertheless, I cannot observe a place where it displays how many reviews I have done under each category.

So, is there any way to check it or is that a feature still not available in StackOverflow?

Thank you for your valuable time and attention.

Comment: You don't need to hide your reviews. We have all access to that tab. Only your Votes tab is private.

Comment:  I am a little bit new to the site. yet learning its all functions and features. I was searching for such a 'stat' tab under the review tab in the all actions tab. Then I googled and searched in meta StackOverflow. Could not come up with a solution. Your answer was really helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Goto the [Stats](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/stats) tab of any queue:

[image: screenshot showing late answers queue with stat tab (right) highlighted and showing bronze, silver and gold badges and progress in right sidebar.]

Nice benefit is that it also shows the progress to each badge in the right sidebar.

I see I have a gold badge waiting for me ...

Comment: just casually having 5,000 reputation in the achivement trophy.

Comment: it would be cool to see them at once on all sides